# floating to same size boxes side by side

Tags: html, css, forms, mobile

I am struggling to create two boxes that will side by side of top container. All I want to do is have a contact form on the left, and then my details on the right. So that when the window is minimised they both drop down on top of one another.

I have removed some code to simplify matters, please let me know if you require more or all of the HTML.

**HTML**

```
<section>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="dark">
            <div class="callus"><a href="tel:+07756848657"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x" ></i></a></div>
            <h2>Get A Quote</h2>
            <p>DB Plumbing provides a full range of general plumbing and repair services, from installing your new bathroom suite to fixing that leaking tap or joint that has been annoying you for ages.</p>

</div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="dark">
   <div>
  </div>

        <form class="quote">
          <div>
            <label>Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" style="width: 150px;">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Email</label><br>
            <input type="email" style="width: 150px;">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Phone</label><br>  
            <input type="text" style="width: 150px;">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Message</label><br>
            <textarea style="width:250px; height:100px;"></textarea>
          </div>
          <button class="button_1" type="submit" style="width: 

50px;">Send</button>
 </form>

          </div>
      </div>
      </article>
</section>

<footer>
<div>
  <p>Darren Brady Plumbing Copyright &copy; 2017</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  font: 100%/1.5 Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  background-color:white;
}

/* Style the list 'container'  */
ul.topnav {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

/* Float the list items left - this is the 'magic' that turns a vertical list into a horizontal row */
ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}

/* style the links  */
ul.topnav li a {
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;

 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 0.3s;
 font-size: 100%;
}

/* hover */
ul.topnav li a:hover {
color: gold;
}


/* Hide the icon initially  */
ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

/* Global */
.container{
  width:70%;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  /* Allows the burger nav and branding to sit on the same line */


}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 50px;
  color: black;
} 

ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.subscribe{
  height:38px;
  background:gold;
  border:0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right:20px;
  color:black;
}

.dark{
  padding:25px;
  background:#35424a;
  color:white;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}


.maps {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 75%; // This is the aspect ratio
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
}
.maps iframe {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
    }

/* Header **/
header{
  background:#35424a;
  color:white;
  padding-top:30px;
  min-height:70px;
  border-bottom:gold 5px solid;
}

header a{
  color:#ffffff;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size:100%;
}

header li{
  float:left;
  display:inline;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header #branding{
  float:left;
}

header #branding h1{
  margin:0;
}

header nav{
  float:right;
  margin-top:10px;
}

header .highlight{
  color:gold;
}

header a:hover{
  color:gold;
}

h3 .bronze{
  color:#cc6633;

}

h3 .silver{
  color:silver;

}

h3 .gold{
  color:gold;

}

img {
 width:90%;
 height:auto;
}

/* Showcase */
#showcase{
  min-height:400px;
  color:black;
}

#showcase h1{
  margin-top:50px;
  font-size:300%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

#showcase p{
  font-size:120%;
}

/* Newsletter */
#newsletter{
  padding:15px;
  color:#ffffff;
  background:#35424a
}

#newsletter h1{
  float:left;
}

#newsletter form {
  float:right;
  margin-top:15px;
}

#newsletter input[type="email"]{
  padding:4px;
  height:26px;
  width:250px;
}


/* Sidebar */
aside#sidebar{
  float:right;
  width:25%;
  margin-top:10px;
}

section#contactus .quote input, section#contactus .quote textarea{
  width:30%;
  padding:5px;
}

/* Main-col */
article#main-col{
  float:left;
  width:70%;
}


/* Imagery */

#social {
  margin-top: 10%; 
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 150%;
    color: black;
}

#imagery {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

#imagery .box {
float: right;
text-align: center;
width: 30%;
padding:10px;

}

#imagery .box i{
  font-size: 700%;
}

/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px;

}

.column img {
    margin-top: 12px;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.container .visuals{
  float: right;
}

.container .callus{
  float: right
}

.fa-phone {
 color: gold;
}


/* Services */
ul#services li{
  list-style: none;
  padding:20px;
  border: #cccccc solid 1px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  background:#35424a;
  color: white;
}


footer{
  padding:20px;
  margin-top:20px;
  color:black;
  background-color:gold;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Media Queries */
@media(max-width: 768px){
  header #branding,
  header nav,
  header nav li,
  #newsletter h1,
  #newsletter form,
  #boxes .box,
  article#main-col,
  aside#sidebar{
    float:none;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
  }

  header{
    padding-bottom:20px;
  }



  #showcase h1{
    margin-top:40px;
  }

  #newsletter button, .quote button{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
  }

  #newsletter form input[type="email"], .quote input, .quote textarea{
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:5px;
  }


  /* nav */
 ul.topnav li {
  display: none;
}

ul.topnav li.icon {
 display: inline-block;
 }


ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
 ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 }
 ul.topnav.responsive li {
 float: none;   /*  'un' float the list items so they return to displaying vertically */
 display: inline;
 }
 ul.topnav.responsive li a {
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
 }
}

/* 400 pixels */
@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
  header #branding, header nav, header nav li {
    text-align: center;
    width:115%;
    font-size: 100%
  }
  header ul{
  padding:10px;
  font-size: 100%;
  }

#social {
  font-size: 150%;
}

#showcase {
  min-height: 400px;
  font-size: 80%;
}

#imagery .box{
  size: 10px 10px;

}

/*css reset
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers 
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
  background-image: url("bg.jpg");
  background-size: cover;  /*this seems better*/
  /*background-size: contain;

}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* end reset */
```

Comment: You provided really messed up chunk of code. Other simplify it more or give more details of what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I tried understanding your code but it was alttle difficult to know what you wanted.
I hope this helps

```
    <html>
    <head>

    <!--add these bootstap links to your head section-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <section>

        <div class="row"> // this class helps you create a rows using bootstrap's grid layout
            <div class="container col-md-5"> // now you can add the col-md-5 
                                   //class toy your divs to make            them side by side but responsive
                <div class="dark">
                    <div class="callus"><a href="tel:+07756848657"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x" ></i></a></div>
                    <h2>Get A Quote</h2>
                    <p>DB Plumbing provides a full range of general plumbing and repair services, from installing your new bathroom suite to fixing that leaking tap or joint that has been annoying you for ages.</p>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container col-md-7"> // this makes a larger column for you
                <div class="dark">
                    <div>
                    </div>

                    <form class="quote">
                        <div>
                            <label>Name</label><br>
                            <input type="text" style="width: 150px;">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Email</label><br>
                            <input type="email" style="width: 150px;">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Phone</label><br>  
                            <input type="text" style="width: 150px;">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Message</label><br>
                            <textarea style="width:250px; height:100px;"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button class="button_1" type="submit" style="width: 50px;">Send</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>

    <footer>
        <div>
            <p>Darren Brady Plumbing Copyright &copy; 2017</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if you have interned connection whenever you load the page. else you can download the bootstrap files from their site and add them to your project then link them as any other css or js resource

Comment: I hope that it helped